# Dockers create user namespaces?

Tags: linux-kernel, docker, namespace, container

My question is about how Docker instrument the storage for the container instance.

Do container applications or Docker create user namespaces when creating a new container instance?

Comment: Yes, they do. Do you have a more specific question, or would you just like to see how that can be seen?

Comment: @Uberhumus yes, I would like to know how the user namespace can be seen. Also, If I disable unprivileged_userns_clone (sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=0) and try to run a docker instance in the unprivileged user, would that fail as docker cannot create a user space now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker creates namespaces. An `lsns` command before after `docker` run would show that there are extra user namespaces created.

Comment: Depends on how you run Docker. By default (and when running as a system service, which is the default when not stated otherwise) it doesn't create *user* namespaces, but can be configured to: lsns would show it didn't.